# Как собрать программу, использующую стороннюю библиотеку

Tags: c++, linux, embedded, кросс-компиляция

Имеется программа, состоящая из одного *.cpp*-файла. Она использует библиотеку libcurl. Необходимо скомпилировать это дело под встраиваемый Linux на процессоре Cortex A7 (arm 32-bit).

Как я понимаю, нужно сконфигурировать, а затем собрать библиотеку под нужную архитектуру, после чего собрать саму программу посредством кросс-платформенного компилятора.

Проблема в том, что я не представляю, как указать компилятору, чтобы *#include*  понимал, что библиотека лежит где-то рядом здесь.

Comment: Собирайте в окружении Buildroot -- гораздо легче и понятнее.

Answer (score 3):

> как там указать, чтобы #include понимал, что библиотека лежит где-то рядом здесь

На самом деле речь о заголовочном файле библиотеки (*.h)

флаг `-I.` (инклюды ищутся в одной папке с компилируемым файлом)

> чтобы линкер знал, где лежит скомпиленная библиотека

флаг `-L.`(в той же папке)

> чтобы при загрузке библиотека искалась в одной папке с исполняемым файлом

флаги -Wl,-R,\$$ORIGIN

Наверняка, этого недостаточно, чтобы решить вашу конкретную задачу, но это три стандартных метода, чтобы собрать и запустить что-то в одной папке. Может чем-то помочь.